# Laravel 7, como chamar iterar um input que nao tem nome certo

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estou a fazer um pequeno formulário em Laravel 7 e em JavaScript tenho um botão que adiciona os campos que o utilizador necessitar para criar as perguntas necessárias.

JavaScript

```
$(btnQuestions).click(function () {
            $('<div class="form-group" id="div_questions"><label for="data_type">Tipo de pergunta</label><input type="text" name="data_type'+i+'" id="data_type'+i+'" class="form-control"><label for="question'+i+'">Pergunta</label><input type="text" name="question'+i+'" id="question'+i+'" class="form-control"></div>').appendTo(divQuestions);
            $('#removehidden').remove();
            i++;
            $('<input type="hidden" name="quantidadeCampos" value="' + i + '" id="removehidden">').appendTo(divQuestions);
        });
```

A minha dúvida agora é como é que no Controller consigo chamar o que é inserido nos inputs sendo que o "name" muda sempre que adicionamos um novo campo

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name_form' =>'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'end_date' => 'required', 
            'data_type' => 'required',
            'question' => 'required'
        ]);

        $form = new Form([
            'name_form' => $request->get('name_form'),
            'description'=> $request->get('description'),
            'email'=> $request->get('email'),
            'end_date' => $request->get('end_date')           
        ]);

        $form->save();

        /*$data_type = $request->get('data_type');
        $quest = $request->get('question');*/
        $questions = array('data_type', 'question');

        for ($i = 1; $i <= count($questions); $i++) {
            $question = new Question([
               'data_type' => $request->get('data_type'),
               'question' => $request->get('question'),
               'form_id' => $form->id
            ]);
            $question->save();
        }

        return redirect('/backoffice/forms')->with('success', 'O formulário foi criado com sucesso.');
    }
```

Se alguém me poder ajudar agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Oi, tudo bom?
Em vez de utilizar `'data_type' + id` no name do input, podemos utilizar um array.

```
<input name="data_type[]">
```

Dessa forma, o request->data_type vai chegar no controller como um `array`, da seguinte forma:

```
data_type = ['Field1', 'Field2'];
```

Dessa forma, quando formos iterar sobre o data_type, teremos toda informação concentrada em um único array de nome `data_type` apenas

```
foreach ($request->data_type as $data_type) {
   dd($data_type); // Return 'Field 1'
}
```

Sendo assim, seu a criação de questões ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
foreach ($request->data_type as $data_type) {
   'data_type' => $data_type,
   'question' => $request->get('question'),
   'form_id' => $form->id
}
```

[Para mais detalhes sobre o array no name](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/a-little-trick-for-grouping-fields-in-an-html-form/)